# reader class not found in GeoIP2

Tags: php, class, geoip

I am trying to install Maxmind's GeoIP2. I did everything by their instructions and I still get this annoying error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'GeoIp2\Database\reader' not found in C:\Program Files\*\*\localweb\GeoIp2\index.php on line 19
```

this is how the script looks like inside index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\reader;
// This creates the Reader object, which should be reused across
// lookups.
$reader = new Reader('C:/Program Files/*/*/localweb/GeoIp2/Database/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
$record = $reader->country('128.101.101.101');
?>
```

Anybody can help please ?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me thanks @Greg Oschwald! 
Since I'm not using composer, my code now is:

```
<?php
require 'geoip2.phar';
try {
    $reader = new GeoIp2\Database\Reader('GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
    $record = $reader->city('128.101.101.101');
    print($record->country->isoCode . "\n"); // 'US'
    print($record->country->name . "\n"); // 'United States'
    print($record->country->names['zh-CN'] . "\n"); // '??'
    print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name . "\n"); // 'Minnesota'
    print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->isoCode . "\n"); // 'MN'
    print($record->city->name . "\n"); // 'Minneapolis'
    print($record->postal->code . "\n"); // '55455'
    print($record->location->latitude . "\n"); // 44.9733
    print($record->location->longitude . "\n"); // -93.2323
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Could not open Phar: ', $e;
}
```

Took that phar file from https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php/releases

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

use GeoIp2\Database\reader;

to:

use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

Answer (score 0):

Try to up php version to 7.1.33 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install GeoIP2 package:

```
composer require geoip2/geoip2
```